# What can I use instead of items() method to display keys and values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to display both the keys and values of my dictionary without using the items() method. How can I achieve this desired output without using the items() method:

```
1 cubed is 1
3 cubed is 27
5 cubed is 125
7 cubed is 343
9 cubed is 729
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
numbers = [1,3,5,7,9]
cubes = {item:item**3 for item in numbers}
for key in cubes.keys():
    for val in cubes.values():
        print(f'{key} cubed is {val}')
```

Comment: Are `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` not good enough for you? They are iterators that you can go over in a `for` loop.

Comment: how would I use those in a for loop though to create the desired output?

Comment: `list(dict.keys())` and `list(dict.values())` return list of the dict's keys and values, respectively. Can you elaborate a little on your original question?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `.items()` if you want the keys and values?

Comment: Do you really need the `cubes` dictionary for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to display both the key and value without using the `items()` method. It is iterating over the keys and get the value of the key.

```
numbers = [1,3,5,7,9]
cubes = {item:item**3 for item in numbers}
for key in cubes:
    val = cubes[key]
    print(f'{key} cubed is {val}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer has been solved based on the comments, but I wanted to help answer it to help out everyone else with this same issue.

Based on your example, you should be able to use items that would work even better than what you have. You can loop through keys and values at the same time. Below is an example.

```
numbers = [1,3,5,7,9]
cubes = {item:item**3 for item in numbers}

for key, value in cubes.items():
    print(f"{key} cubed is {value}")
```

Of course you can always loop through just the keys and use those keys to get the value directly from the dictionary. You can do this in two ways, and both will provide the same result. Here is an example of what I mean.

```
for key in cubes.keys():
    print(f"{key} cubed is {cubes[key]}")
```

Or

```
for key in cubes:
    print(f"{key} cubed is {cubes[key]}")
```

Both will effectively loop through the keys only. You can also loop through just the values, but you won't be able to easily do anything with the key since you are only looping through a list of values. An example of this is below.

```
for value in cubes.values():
    # do something with only the value
    ...
```